# ApplicationUser class (to define Extented Properties) in .NET 6. I am not getting the user data using the ApplicationUser properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

*I define the ApplicationUser class to add some additional column into User table. But i am not able to get data from  User table by using ApplicationUser properties.*

**1. Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, MailJetEmailSender>();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opt => 
{
    opt.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
    opt.Password.RequireLowercase=true;
    opt.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    opt.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 2;
});
```

**2. ApplicationUser.cs**
*Here is code to get the user data*

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Role { get; set; }

}
```

**3. ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext:IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    { }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Use seed method here
        builder.Seed();
    }
}
```

**4. Controllercode**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    
     var userList = await _db.ApplicationUser.ToListAsync();
    
    var userRole = await _db.UserRoles.ToListAsync();
    var roles = await _db.Roles.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var user in userList)
    {
        var role = userRole.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == user.Id);
        if (role == null)
        {
            user.Role = "None";
        }
        else
        {
            user.Role = roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == role.RoleId).Name;
        }
    }

    return View(userList);
}
```

Comment: What data are you not getting? This looks to be some "smelly" code to me. Don't pollute your entities with properties that you only need for your business logic later, map them into classes that are actually useful.

Comment: So you are getting empty data in `_db.ApplicationUser.ToListAsync`? Could you please share your entity models design or how the data is residing in your asp.net users table? In addition, please remove your sensitive information if there are any.

Comment: Thanks Md Farid Uddin Kiron for your cooperation, it has been sorted. I was trying to show IdentityUser data that was created using the seeding. When i created new user using the registration page it is saving as ApplicationUser  which is showing in UI.

Comment: Glad to know that you were able to resolve your issue, I am privileged to assist you on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ApplicationUser class (to define Extented Properties) in .NET 6. I am
> not getting the user data using the ApplicationUser properties

Well, based on your description and shared code snippet it appeared that, you have few misunderstanding about [asp.net core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#view-the-identity-database) functionality.

In asp.net core identity table we have following table by design:

[image]

So when you extend ApplicationUser from IdentityUser it usually save records into AspNetUsers table.

If you're unable to retrieve user data with the code

```
var userList = await _db.ApplicationUser.ToListAsync();
```

It's likely because you're trying to access the `ApplicationUser` class directly, but as said earlier the user data is typically stored in the `AspNetUsers` table which managed by [ASP.NET Core Identity.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Therefore, in order to retrieve user data, you should use the UserManager and access the users through it. So you can do as following:

```
var aspnetList = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();

Instead Of 

var userList = _context.ApplicationUser.ToListAsync();
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please remember that, If you've extended the ApplicationUser class in ASP.NET Core Identity to add additional columns to the User table, so in this scenario you cannot able to extract data directly from ApplicationUser rather you should use [_userManager.Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). If you want to study more [please refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)